# Error in make file for device driver Hello world

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, makefile, linux-device-driver

I have simple code with device driver hello world with a make file.it was executed well in case of 12.04 LTS but recently i have upgrade my ubuntu to 14.04 after this the same program not able to compiled.
with error message on

```
make

make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 5):

your make file does't work for other versions of the kernel since the kernel library modules will be in /lib/modules/kernelversion/build.

so you should use
make -C /lib/modules/"should be the current running kernel"/build

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Which will automatically loads the current running kernel version using "shell uname -r".

Sample makefile

```
KERNELDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
CLEANFILE := *.dis *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.*.old
obj-m := hello.o

    default:
            make -C $(KERNELDIR)  M=$(CURDIR) modules

    clean:
            rm -f $(CLEANFILE)
```

Comment: [See my comment here against using `PWD` and for using `CURDIR`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353795/error-in-make-file-for-device-driver-hello-world#comment45069708_28354020).

Answer (score 1):

You are expected to post the content of your Makefile in your question. 
Anyways, I think, there is some problem in your Makefile. Instead of specifying the kernel version as `3.13.0-45-generic` , you should write `$(shell uname -r)` so that it can dynamically get the currently running kernel version. With upgrading ubuntu, your kernel version changed. So, it's not working anymore.

Create you Makefile as follows provided your device driver program file name is *hello.c*

```
obj-m += hello.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(CURDIR) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(CURDIR) clean
```

The execution of '*make*' command starts by changing its directory to the one provided with the -C option that is **/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build** which is your kernel source directory and The M= option causes that makefile to move back into your module source directory as **CURDIR**(*current directory*) is always set to current working directory.

Reply if it's still not working. [This pdf](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf) can help you as a quick reference if you are beginner in this field. And if you want to become an expert in linux device driver programming in future, follow [This Book](http://free-electrons.com/doc/books/ldd3.pdf). It's worth reading.

Comment: why dont you define PWD?

Comment: You don't need to define PWD. It's always defined automatically as an environment variable. This '*make*' command starts by changing its directory to the one provided with the -C option (that is, your kernel source directory) and The M= option causes that makefile to move back into your module source directory which is always automatically got defined by PWD.  You can check value of PWD by throwing the *pwd* command on terminal.

Comment: Please don't use `PWD`, but `CURDIR` instead. `PWD` is an environment variable that doesn't get passed to `sudo`. So if you want to install your module, this becomes a problem. In fact, as the OP has "M=" with no parameter, it is even likely that he has used `PWD` copying from internet and `make`d with `sudo`. `CURDIR` is a GNU extension (which is ok, because kernel `Makefile`s are GNU anyway) which is always guaranteed to set. [Read google.](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=make+curdir+instead+of+pwd)

Comment: use of PWD does not create any problem here as I have created my own device driver before. `insmod`ing with `sudo`  installed the module without any failure everytime. But, your advice is reasonable enough. So, I am editing my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati, sure. I wasn't talking about `insmod` though, I was talking about installing the module alongside other modules in the kernel, with the `modules_install` target of kernel's Makefiles.

Comment: @Shahbaz Oh sorry. I misunderstood that. Yeah. In that case, `PWD` can create problem. Thank you again for that great info.